# How to deal with application/octet-stream type API response

Tags: java, c#, php, python, .net

I have received a response from the API as string and based on the documentation the response will be as mentioned below.

*application/octet-stream       Content created by requested job in a gzip compressed file.*

The string response I received is in a binary format and I see .csv file name as well in there [Please click here to see the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy2C6.png). I don't see this file either in bin folder of the project or in AppData. I searched for this file whole file system but no luck.

Anyone came across such response? Let me know if any improvements required in my question.

Comment: Without code it is very hard to understand what exactly is the problem... I.e. why do you expect "Respons from an API" to show up as file somewhere?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually it's a simple GET request and the response received is as mentioned in the question. Yeah, I was expecting some file to be present somewhere in app data or bin folder in my project.

Comment: First Convert the binary format array to string and check, what is in there?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the output is in GZip stream which is compressed format.

Below are the links I found very useful.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27203/GZipStream-Compress-Decompress-a-string

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx